# Extracting string variable from tkinter curselection

Tags: string, tkinter, listbox, selection

Quick question :

I run a TKinter prompt on Python 3.6 and I would like to create a variable from the curselection function inside my listbox. I would like to keep the string of that variable so that I could use it later for naming other variables for instance.

Here's my code :

```
#Extracting municipalities from shapefile
MunList = []
MunMap = arcpy.env.workspace +'\munic_s.shp'
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(MunMap)
for row in cursor:
    MunVar = row.getValue("munic_s_24")
    MunList.append(MunVar)
del cursor
MunList = sorted(MunList)
print(MunList)

def test(event=None):
    #print(listbox.get(ACTIVE))
    print(listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))


root = Tk()
root.title("Scrolldown Menu")
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(root, selectmode=SINGLE)
for lines in MunList:
    listbox.insert(END, lines)
listbox.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
listbox.config(borderwidth=3, exportselection=0, height=20, width=50)
print(listbox.bbox(0))
(listbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", test))
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

I create a 'test' function that selects the ACTIVE item on my cursor and bind it to my listbox with a double-click. When I run it and double-click any name in my list, it prints it. However, I can't seem to be able to make a string variable out of it. When I try something like this :

```
test_var = (listbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", test))
print(test_var)
```

I get some sort of index :

```
257891528test
```

But I need the actual string of the variable (example : Washington)

Thanks!

Comment: You can set `test_var` in `test()` function: `test_var = listbox.get(ACTIVE)`.

Comment: It prints the value, but only of the first entry of my list, no matter if i double-click another name. For instance, if I have 100 names in my list, I can click any name I want but the print of test_var always is the first name in my list.

Comment: I don't have your problem in my sample code.  Can you update your code in the question with the changes you have made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same question, I found the answer :

```
root = Tk()
root.title("TEST_TK_Scroll menu")
# Add a grid
mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.pack(pady=100, padx=100)
def close_window ():
    root.destroy()
button = Button (text= 'Confirm selection', command=close_window)
button.pack()
sel=[]
def selection(event):
    selected = (listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))
    print(selected)
    sel.append(selected)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(mainframe)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listbox = Listbox(mainframe, selectmode=SINGLE)
for lines in MunList:
    listbox.insert(END, lines)
listbox.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
listbox.config(borderwidth=3, exportselection=0, height=20, width=50)
#cur1 = listbox.get(selected)
#index1 = listbox.get(0, "end").index(cur1)
(listbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", selection))
print(listbox.bbox(0))
root.mainloop()
print('answer :')
print(sel)
def attempt2(string):
    for v in ("[", "]", "'"):
        string = string.replace(v, "")
    return string
select=sel[0]
attempt2(select)
print(select)
```